# Android, different layout for 10.1 and 9.7 inch displays

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, tablet, screen-resolution

I've developed an app for an specific **10.1 inch display (2560x1600)** and my layout files are written to fit that specific resolution.

Now I need to make the same app to work with a**n 9.7 inch display (2048x1536).**
It's the first time I have to do a thing like this and I don't know which is the right approach. Using the actual layout file in the new tablet is a bit of a mess,  nothing fits correctly, is like making a zoom in the old one.

I've read a bit about creating folders for different layouts, but the problem is that if I create a folder "**layout-sw720dp"** both tablets use the same layout, which I don't want to.
Is the **"different layout files"** the right approach? If so, how can I specify a layout for an specific "resolution" or whatsoever?

Is there other way to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, there are different types of attribute qualifiers which helps us to design the app for different types/resolutions of devices. However in this particular case here, both the resolutions would come under the same attributes for almost all the qualifier types.

They both would come under the `xhdpi` bracket for `xlarge` devices. So you cannot use these qualifiers. But the one thing that is not same will be the `shortest width` qualifier for the two resolutions.

The shortest width for **2560 x 1600** would be **800dp** and shortest width for **2048 x 1536** would be **768dp**. So you can use the `layout-sw<>dp` attribute to distinguish the two devices.

for 10.1 inch display (2560 x 1600) : `layout-sw800dp`
for 9.7 inch display (2048 x 1536) : `layout-sw768dp`

When you use the `layout-sw720dp` folder, both the devices will take the same folder as the shortest width of both devices are greater than 720. Check this [developer doc section](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) (especially the table) for more information.

Comment: This is it! So the "xxx"dp thing is the resolution / 2 ? and, how is it that when i create a new virtual device with this resolution and screen dimension android studio choose automatically the "800dp" version instead of the 768dp version? (maybe it deserves another question here...)

Comment: Nope, it is not always be resolution/2. It'll be based on the density of the device with the resolution. Here it is like that. `xhdpi = 320dp = 2 x mdpi (Base density)`

Answer (score 1):

In the app folder of your application in android studio , go to the res-> layout, right click on that select New -> Layout resource file. on the new resource file window ,give file name dimens.
on the available qualifiers select dimension and push it into the chosen qualifier and specify the dimension as 2048x1536. you can use this file to specify the layout for tablet of dimension 2048x1536.

Answer (score 0):

If you layouts are properly designed **layout-sw720dp** should handle both tablets flawlessly.

> how can I specify a layout for an specific "resolution" or whatsoever?

For this part there are 2 types of width prefixes. **layout-wXXX** is for devices whose width is exactly XXX, nothing more, nothing less. Whereas, **layout-swXXX** is for devices whose width is at least XXX.

Again, well designed **layout-sw720dp** folder should cover both your needs.

Comment: Well, I think you're right Eric, it is not well designed because it was designed with a very specific device in mind, so null flexibility.